# How to install php5 curl in mac osx snow leopard?

Tags: php, macos, osx-snow-leopard

How can I install php5 curl module or any other php5 modules in mac osx snow leopard?

In Ubuntu 9.04 I am using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

I already tried Googling but can't find some solution.

Answer (score 18):

I would install it via [macports](http://www.macports.org/install.php).  Once you've installed mac ports, you can use it to build and then install php5 curl with the command

```
sudo port install php5-curl
```

I was able to determine what the mac ports package name was by using the ports search function:

```
port search curl
```

Edit:  You must have Apple Developer tools (X Code) installed on your machine for mac ports to work.  X Code can be downloaded free from Apple.  It also should be on your second Snow Leopard installation disc.

As a developer working on Apple machines, I find ports indispensable.  It's rare that I get through an entire project without relying on it for some dependency, especially when I am using a lot of open source libraries.  It's worth spending some time looking around and seeing what else is in there.

Comment: install time remaining, less than a minute. - its been 15 minutes already. Hhmmm...

Comment: There is an error aftermathew when installing php5-curl: $ sudo port install php5-curl
--->  Computing dependencies for php5-curlError: Unable to execute port: can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path: '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that you MUST have Apple Developer Tools (X Code Installed before you can use Mac Ports.  Mac Ports uses Apple Developer Tools to build your packages.   It appears you don't have make on your machine.  Installing X Code Will give you make.

Comment: The latest release of XCode for Mountain Lion separates the tools from a single installer.  You need XCode command line tools installed.